# Ruby validator with Regex is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I have a ruby regex I made usinig Rubular
http://rubular.com/r/RRc8twB6NL which is meant to check for a decimal 10.00 for pricing.  I get it to work on Rubular, but in my application this code does not work:

```
validates_format_of :price, :with=>/^([0-9]{1,}\.{0,}[0-9]{0,2})$/
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your regular expression (which could be rewritten as /^\d+\.*\d?\d?/) matches any string consisting of 3 or more digits and any string consisting of 1 or more digits, then some dots and then 0 to 2 digits (any string containing such a line, in fact). This includes "0007", "0...." and other non-prices. What do you really want to validate?

Comment: @undur_gongor I just wanted to validate that it would be in format of a price such as $1.00, $10.00, $200.00, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you only want to have prices with one digit and then zeros you need the regex

```
/\A[1-9]0*\.\d\d\z/
```

If any number is allowed before the decimal dot it is

```
/\A[1-9]\d*\.\d\d\z/
```

If the fraction part is optional it is either of

```
/\A[1-9]0*(\.\d\d)?\z/
/\A[1-9]\d*(\.\d\d)?\z/
```

If you want to allow for the dollar sign (maybe with spaces in between) it is either of

```
/\A(\$\s*)?[1-9]0*\.\d\d\z/
/\A(\$\s*)?[1-9]\d*\.\d\d\z/
/\A(\$\s*)?[1-9]0*(\.\d\d)?\z/
/\A(\$\s*)?[1-9]\d*(\.\d\d)?\z/
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for 10.00:

```
/^10\.00$/
```

To check for 10.00 - 99.99:

```
/^[1-9]\d\.\d{2}$/
```